# Error querying database. Cause: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mapped Statements collection does not contain value for getSecurityRowCount

Tags: java, sql, mybatis, spring-mybatis

Below is my mybatis.xml file -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">
<mapper namespace="com.principal.pfunds.service.rest.jdbcmanager.SecurityManagers">
<select id="getSecurityRowCount" parameterType="com.principal.pfunds.service.rest.mybatis.SecurityParam"
    resultType="java.lang.Integer">
    SELECT COUNT(*) ROWSCOUNT 
    FROM 
        ${schema}.A_PDC_SCRTY 
    WHERE 
        TOKEN_ID = #{tokenID}
        AND RSLT_TYP = #{resultType} 
        AND SVC_CD = #{svcCode}
</select>
```

And I am calling this query using below code statement-

```
Integer securityRowCount = getSqlSession().selectOne("getSecurityRowCount", securityParam);
```

I am trying to get row count but it is giving me error as:

```
Exception in getSecurityRowCount(): org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
### Error querying database.  Cause: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mapped Statements collection does not contain value for getSecurityRowCount
### Cause: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mapped Statements collection does not contain value for getSecurityRowCount
[4/13/17 22:05:17:734 IST] 000000a4 SystemOut     O
```

Please help me out. I am not able to understand what went wrong here. Thanks!

Comment: you should specify that you are using `mybatis-spring`

Comment: could you please help me in that. I do not have any idea about it. How to specify it?

Comment: Nevermind, I have actually submitted revision of your question that has been accepted. I added _spring-mybatis_ tag + a couple of formatting. @Jordan Lewis then updated a line in formatting.

Comment: Now try what I propose in my answer and tell me how it works.

Comment: @blackwizard :- Thank you so much for your help. Actually my code is working now. I just restarted my RAD and everything is fine now.
No idea why it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

In the [documentation](http://www.mybatis.org/spring/sqlsession.html), statement is referenced by its full qualified name (prefix statement id with namespace):

```
selectOne("com.principal.pfunds.service.rest.jdbcmanager.SecurityManagers.getSecurityRowCount", securityParam);
```